# combining 2 strings in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

I have a problem when I try to combine 2 `NSString`

I extract 2 `NSSring` form a JSON and its diagrams are:

thumbList: ( "picture1.jpg", "picture2.jpg", "picture3.jpg" ... )

fullnameList: ("name1", "name2" , "name3" ... )

My intention is unite them into one using the following scheme:
("name1", "picture1.jpg", "name2", "picture2.jpg", "name3", "picture3.jpg"...)

```
NSArray *array_webdata=[[NSArray array] init];

NSString *searchStatus = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];    
array_webdata = [parsedata objectWithString:searchStatus error:nil];

//String with all data of each user
NSString *usersList = [array_webdata valueForKey:@"results"];    
NSLog(@"\n results? = %@ \n", usersList);

//String with thumbs
NSString *thumbList = [usersList valueForKey:@"thumb"];
NSLog(@"\n thumbs? = %@ \n", thumbList);

//String with usernames
NSString *fullnameList = [usersList valueForKey:@"fullname"];
NSLog(@"\n fullnames? = %@ \n", fullnameList);


NSMutableIndexSet *indexes = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1];
[indexes addIndex:3];    
[fullnameList insertObjects:thumbList atIndexes:indexes];
NSLog(@"array: %@", fullnameList);
```

But when I try to execute shows the next error message: **[__NSArrayI insertObjects:atIndexes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.**

Can anyone help me?

Comment: "insertObjects:atIndexes:" can not be used with nsstring...

Comment: It's not an NSString issue. The problem is he's calling insertObject:atIndexes: on an `NSArray` (immutable) when he should be creating `fullnameList` as an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: bt he declarfed fullnameList as nsstring right??

Comment: Yes, I declare fullnameList as nsstring but if declare it as nsmutablestring happens the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
 NSMutableDictionary* dataDict =   [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:picturesList   forKeys:namesList];
 // Whenever key needed for fetching record from Dictionary just write       
 NSArray* keyArr = [dataDict AllKey];
```

Now you have all key and you can fetch record with the help of above key.

Answer (score 1):

All  *"unrecognized selector sent to instance."* errors mean the same: you think some object has a method, but it really don't have it at runtime.

Due to the dynamic nature of Objective-C, if you're not sure of some object having a method you should always test it calling respondsToSelector: like this:

```
if ([myObj respondsToSelector:@selector(someMethod)]) {
    [myObj someMethod];
}
```

In this case,

```
NSString *fullnameList = [usersList valueForKey:@"fullname"];
```

is a NSString. That class does not have a insertObjects:atIndexes: method. Maybe you have to declare it as an NSMutableArray

Comment: If I change that line like that:     NSMutableArray *fullnameList = [usersList valueForKey:@"fullname"];
The error message is the same